# how can I specify the location, scale, and shape parameters for K-S test in R?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov

In the K-S test I read

( In order for the test to work, you must specify the location, scale, and shape parameters. If these parameters are estimated from the data, it invalidates the test. If you don’t know these parameters, you may want to run a less formal test (like the one outlined in the empirical distribution function article).

If I generate data from N(1,4) and from t(5) of size 10, how can I specify the location, scale, and shape parameters? If I using a one-sample K-S test in R

I used this code

```
ks.test(rnorm(10,1,4),"pnorm")
ks.test(rt(10,5),"pnorm")
```

Comment: `ks.test(rt(10,5),"pnorm", mean = 1, sd = 4)`? The parameters go in the dots argument, see `help("ks.test")`.